# Java Swing - How to override the tray 'displayMessage' popup?

Tags: java, swing, system-tray, tray

I set up a tray for my application and when an event occurs the 'displayMessage(String, String, Icon)' method is called. Is there anyway to override the paint method of this popup to make it look different?

Edit: No-one?

Comment: With .NET (especially WPF) you can do some really fancy messages.  But then you have to use .NET ;o)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible since the tray is coming from OS. Your best bet is to modify the appearance of the message on the OS configuration, which of course will change not only yours.